# Use Camera to Take Photos and Save them to the Phone Gallery

Tags: java, android

I am new to Android Studio. I want to capture photo with phone camera by clicking a button, then display the taken photo, and the photo will save automatically in the phone gallery. I have found some online examples but the photo that I captured is not saved inside the gallery. I already used the code below. May I get some help please?

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.buttonTakePhoto:
            Intent intent=new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);
            break;
    }
} 

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST) {
        Bitmap image = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        ImageView imageview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        imageview.setImageBitmap(image);
    }
}
```

Comment: Since you received the Bitmap - why can't you just save it to the gallery with MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage() ?

Answer (score 1):

To Take image by using camera intent and store it in gallery use this and you will get result in `onActivityResult`

```
    private void takeImageFromCamera() {
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        File exportDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "TempFolder");
        if (!exportDir.exists()) {
            exportDir.mkdirs();
        } else {
            exportDir.delete();
        }
        File mTempCameraPhotoFile = new File(exportDir, "/" + UUID.randomUUID().toString().replaceAll("-", "") + ".jpg");
        Log.d("TAG", "/" + UUID.randomUUID().toString().replaceAll("-", "") + ".jpg");
        takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(mTempCameraPhotoFile));


        startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, Config.CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);

    }
}
```